# infinity scroll in reactjs fixed data table

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

I need to implement infinity scroll features for fixed data table.
I checked API doc, there is no events dispatched when user scroll to the end of the table. The only seemly helpful event is onScrollEnd, but that event gives me back scrollX and scrollY. 
ScrollY is pretty huge, I don't know how to use this number to detect user is scrolling near the end.
Can anyone tell me how I can implement infinity scroll feature using fixed data table?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame that such component does not have proper API for infinite scroll.
The solution is this (but it is ugly):

The onScrollEnd() returns you a scrollY value. You need to persist this value in component state, e.g. `this.state.scroll`. On each onScrollEnd, you have to check for equality:

`this.state.scroll === nextState.scroll && nextState.scroll !== 0 // you dont want to load dada on scrollTop`.

If this is true, then you can load additional data, update your store or what you have, and re-render the component.

BIG PROBLEM: the onScrollEnd() function is very very slow :( Maybe do debouncing/throttling?